# Do Expect Scripts mesh ok with CI/CD tools like Jenkins and Bamboo?

Tags: jenkins, testing, bamboo

I am primarily interested in Jenkins and Bamboo and how onerous any interactions they have with Expect Scripts might be.

I know there are some gotchas.

I am building some automated test scripts from scratch and have found Expect Scripts to be very helpful, particularly because they default to just dealing with text that a user would see, and they don't care where it came from; which is good for what I'm doing. I only care about what gets entered into a CLI and what get's spit back.

So far I've encountered one binary that was sourcing text from some pseudo-terminal and normal UNIX redirection (`$binary args > output_log.file`) just doesn't want to populate a file; it creates a file but the file's empty. This is not a bug I care about, I just want something that will interact with the CLI the way a human tester would.

Hence, why Expect has it's advantages. But my scripts will probably need to interact with Jenkins or Bamboo at some point.

Should I get a heads up? Or are the issues I'm likely to encounter not something to worry about until later on?

Answer (score 0):

Both Jenkins and Bamboo will allow you to add scripting tasks.  In the case of Bamboo you may have to add the path to Expect as an environment variable, Jenkins may have a plugin available.

So you should be able to combine these Continuous Integration systems with your Expect scripts.